# Highchart save chart image using cURL

Tags: php, curl, highcharts

I am using HighCharts and saving image of chart using cURL. It is working fine at my localhost. But when I try the same code on server, the image is blank. And in server error_log I found this warning message:

```
PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): '10361254147.jpeg' is not a valid JPEG file in public_html/project/assign_img.php on line 34
```

The code that I am using is as below:

```
$imgNm = 'https://export.highcharts.com/charts/chart.2ce468213abe432aa1c288339f90171e.jpeg';
$img = 'xyz.jpeg';
$ch = curl_init($imgNm);
$fp = fopen($img, "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
```

Not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: Your provided link is responding with http status 404

Comment: This is just a reference URL.. the one I am generating works well and generate image at my localhost. But not working on Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line for SSL verification to be false and the code worked fine for me.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save your file and show in your browser you don't need cURL:

```
$imgNm    = 'https://export.highcharts.com/charts/chart.2ce468213abe432aa1c288339f90171e.jpeg';
$filename = 'xyz.jpeg';

$image_data = file_get_contents($imgNm);
file_put_contents($filename, __DIR__ . '/' . $imgNm);
```

After this the file is save in same directory as your script (named 'xyz.jpeg') and you can use it in whatever way you want

Comment: I have already used file_get_contents, but it is not working.. that's why I used curl.